# How to set a selected image to multiple UIImageViews

Tags: ios, uiimageview, viewcontroller

Hey guys so I'm creating an iOS application and I am successful at taking a picture in the application either from the camera or the photos and storing it in my database and retrieving it.

I have about 30 different screens (viewcotrollers) on my storyboard, that will all eventually display the users profile picture after the successfully log in. I am wondering how do I go about setting the selected/specific image to all UIImageViews on each screen, do I need to add the same code to each view controller or what.

Sorry if the question is a little vague, I am simply trying to display one image that corresponds to the specific users entry in the database and display it on each of the screen/Viewcontroller's UIImageView.

Any help would be appreciated,

Steven

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question.. yes you need to do the same code on every view controller if you want all of them to show the specific image. but in order to decrease the code quantity you can create an extension (separate swift file):

```
extension UIImageView {
   func setChosenImage {
      let image = // get your image from database
      self.image = image
   }
}
```

If it doesn't help then I may be didn't get your question, sorry :)

Also there might be a better solution but we need to know more. Why do you need to display same image on 30 ViewControllers ? May be you can create 1 View Controller and then subclass from it.

Comment: Most screens will have different actions but the profile image will be displayed on all of them. is the code you provided code that I can add to each view controller to have them display the image from the database, or is that the code for using one extension file and making it a subclass?

Answer (score 0):

I would subclass `UIImageView` to something like `UIPortraitImageView` which then will setup itself with the image from whereever it can be found, maybe statically:

```
class UIPortraitImageView : UIImageView {
    static var thePortraitImage = UIImage()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(image img:UIImage?) {
        super.init(image:img)
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(image:UIPortraitImageView.thePortraitImage)
    }
}

// Initialize it somewhere:
UIPortraitImageView.thePortraitImage = UIImage(named:"D70_4966.JPG")!

// Use it anywhere
var p = UIPortraitImageView()
```

You could also use the `UIPortraitView` in storyboards / .xib-Files by specifying the custom class, as shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to not have to use custom code in your view controllers at all, you could use the approach @AndreasOetjen describes in his answer: Create a custom subclass of UIImageView.

Rather than making it the custom image view look for a static file, however, I would write it to see the image in memory. One way to do that is to set up a singleton data container class that holds an optional UIImage:

```
static userImageLoadedNotice: String = "userImageLoaded"

public class DataSingleton {
  static let sharedDataSingleton = DataSingleton()

  public var userImage: UIImage? {
    didSet{
      NotificationCenter.post(name: userImageLoadedNotice, object: nil)
    }
}
```

The above class will broadcast a notification when the user image is loaded/changed.

Then set up your image view to try to load the user image when it's initialized, and also register for a notification if the image is changed:

```
UIPortraitImageView : UIImageView {
  static var thePortraitImage = UIImage()

  var observer: Any?

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    observer = NotificationCenter.addObserver(forName: userImageLoadedNotice, 
      obj: nil, queue: nil) {
        self.image = DataSingleton.sharedDataSingleton.userImage
    }
    self.image = DataSingleton.sharedDataSingleton.userImage

  }

  override init(image img:UIImage?) {
    super.init(image:img)
    observer = NotificationCenter.addObserver(forName: userImageLoadedNotice, 
      obj: nil, queue: nil) {
        self.image = DataSingleton.sharedDataSingleton.userImage
    }
    self.image = DataSingleton.sharedDataSingleton.userImage
  }
  deinit {
    NotificationCenter.removeObjserver(observer)
  }
}
```

I banged out the code above in the SO editor. It is not perfect, and will need to be cleaned up before it will compile. It's not meant to be copy-paste ready.